# Entity framework produces left join when condition on foreign key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql, ef-core-5.0

I have 2 models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(100)] 
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(500)] 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use this query to retrieve all questionnaires of certain user:

```
List<Questionnaire> questionnaires = this._dbContext.Questionnaires.Where(a => a.User.Id == 1).ToList();
```

It works, but entity framework produces this sql query:

```
SELECT `q`.`Id`, `q`.`Title`, `q`.`UserId`
FROM `Questionnaires` AS `q`
     LEFT JOIN `Users` AS `u` ON `q`.`UserId` = `u`.`Id`
WHERE `u`.`Id` = 1;
```

In my opinion, left join is unnecessary. Please is there any workaround to avoid this left join? Thank you in advance.

Comment: EF core version? Or EF 6

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2

Comment: Please tag appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to expose `UserId` property on `Questionnaire` manually:

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(500)] 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in query instead of `a.User.Id`:

```
var questionnaires = this._dbContext.Questionnaires
    .Where(a => a.UserId == 1) // use UserId instead of User.Id
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is highly counterintuitive. Do you happen to know the reason for this behavior?

Comment: @aluan-haddad check out my answer.

Comment: @AluanHaddad not sure (have not bother to look into source code) but I would say reason for it is how the expression tree is visited, obviously you can implement `User.Id` to be handled without join (note that even with exposed `UserId`, `User.Id` still will end in the join), but it will make EF Core code a little bit more convoluted. Maybe later this will be supported but ATM I bet there are a lot of more important features then this one.

Answer (score 1):

For more information:

[If you choose not to explicitly include a foreign key property in the dependant end of the relationship, EF Core will create a shadow property using the pattern Id](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions). If you look at the `Questionnaire` database table, `UserId` column exists and it has created by EF core as a shadow foreign key.

When you refer `User` inside where clause `_dbContext.Questionnaires.Where(a => a.User.Id == 1)`, EF Core translate linq query into TSQL left join.

You can also use shadow property do define foreign key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Questionnaire>()
        .Property<int>("UserId");

    builder.Entity<Questionnaire>()
        .HasOne(e => e.User)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

Now left join will be replaced with the inner join:

```
SELECT [q].[Id], [q].[Title], [q].[UserId]
      FROM [Questionnaires] AS [q]
      INNER JOIN [Users] AS [c] ON [q].[UserId] = [c].[Id]
      WHERE [c].[Id] = 1
```

To avoid unnecessary join as @Guru Stron said you need to expose `UserId` property on `Questionnaire` class.

Comment: Very interesting. Check to make sure I follow you, it is exposing the key that is associated with the navigation property which makes the difference. In other words, you don't actually have to reference this exposed key in the LINQ query?

Comment: [EF will introduce a shadow property when a relationship is discovered but no foreign key property is found in the dependent entity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#foreign-key-shadow-properties). For performance matters, it's better to expose foreign key.